# How to using regex to get match format?

Tags: php

I have a sample code with "name + version name" format like this:

```
Nokia Belle OS
Symbian Anna OS
Symbian Belle OS, upgradeable to Belle FP1
Symbian OS v9.4, Series 60 rel. 5
```

I using this code get the name and version name:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/(\b+)\s*OS(\s|,)(\b+)/i', $array[], $arr); // with array[] is name of this text

$name = $arr[1][0];
$version = $arr[2][0];
```

But when I try to `var_dump` the `$arr`, it return me `NULL`. So, how can I get the name and version name?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple Regex to get the 'name' and the rest, then use `array_map` to change the content of the rest, like this:

```
<?php
function versionTrim($string) {
  return trim($string, ' ,');
}

$OS = 'Nokia Belle OS
Symbian Anna OS
Symbian Belle OS, upgradeable to Belle FP1
Symbian OS v9.4, Series 60 rel. 5';

preg_match_all('/(.+) OS([^\n]*)/', $OS, $matches);

$names = $matches[1];
$version = array_map(versionTrim, $matches[2]);

var_dump($names);
var_dump($version);
```